# PowerShell ISE - adding createdate of file

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Powershell and looking to leverage it's abilities to assist in an audit.

Trying to get an inventory of all files with a shared drive and the date those files were created.

Using the following code gets me the complete list:
`Get-ChildItem -Path [server name folder name] -Depth 5`

However, the fields returned from the code are: mode, lastwritetime, length and name.  I'd also like to get the date the file was created.

Also, is there a way to remove 'mode' from the returned list?
Is there a way to convert the length from bits to KB or MB?

thank you in advance,
MS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.CreationTime` to get the created date.

```
$target_files = Get-ChildItem "\\server\folder1\folder2\*" -recurse -include "*"
$target_files.CreationTime
```

Using my variable above $target_files, you can view all properties of the object by doing `$target_files | get-member`

The 4 you see are Mode, LastWriteTime, Length, Name. These are just the properties that are output by the command but that is not all of them.

With that said you can control the output using `select-object`

```
$target_files = Get-ChildItem "\\server\folder1\folder2\*" -recurse -include "*"
$target_files | select-object -Property CreationTime, name, @{n='Length';e={$_.Length / 1KB}}
```

Just put any properties you want after the above `-Property` flag. This should take care of your question about not showing "mode"

To get your length into KB or MB or GB or whatever, you just have to do.... length/1kb, length/1mb, etc...

```
foreach($a in $target_files){
    "File: " + $a 
    "Size: " + $a.length/1kb
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly ... thank you so much.  I appreciate your time.

Comment: Delete the comment. I wonder there should be something on the SO to indicate someone is answering or editing( because I falled on embrassing situations like this in the past)